# Rewrite Search URL Permalink For CPT Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy, search, rewrite-rules

My site uses a CPT with custom taxonomies and shows this URL for searches :

https://example.com/?s=&post_type=listing&location=bridgeport&sale_type=for-sale&property_type=office

But what I need is the default URL like this:

https://example.com.com/properties/bridgeport+for-sale+office/

Not sure how to modify this code :

```
add_filter( 'search_rewrite_rules', 'wpse15418_search_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse15418_search_rewrite_rules( $search_rewrite_rules ) {

global $wp_rewrite;

$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%/%', '(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$', '/' );

$search_structure = $wp_rewrite->get_search_permastruct();

return $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $search_structure . '/section/%/%', EP_SEARCH );

}
```

Comment: The default `?s=...` search request in WordPress is transformed into a database query to retrieve matching posts.  You can come up with your own search request that is directed to a page within which you can create a custom query and display the results, e.g. `/my-page?office+forsale+bridgeport`.  If you want to create a custom permalink structure, this is more [complex](https://willnorris.com/2009/06/wordpress-plugin-pet-peeve-2-direct-calls-to-plugin-files/).

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Do you have any code examples please?